# Can a <link /> element's href attribute be relative?

Tags: seo, html, language, hyperlink, relative-urls

Can I use:

```html
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="?l=en" />
```

to link pages with different languages for SEO (recommended for [example by Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en))? Can that URL be relative as in the example above, or does it have to be full (start with `http://example.com`)?

Comment: Note: there is no closing slash on link tags in HTML. That tag is self closing and this is not XHTML.

Comment: @Rob : According to [Free Radical's answer to this question by CaptSaltyJack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898502/4411648), it seems the closing slash is "optional".  Although I'm in favor of using HTML which is not XHTML, I'm not offhand recalling any HTML specification that has forbidden a closing slash.

Comment: @TOOGAM I said nothing about it being forbidden. I am stating that the specification for this element in no way, shape or form, by words or any example anywhere, uses, implies or requires the closing slash. In fact, the spec specifically states browsers are to ignore the slash because it has no meaning, has no value and does nothing. Some people love to bring up the links your CaptSaltyJack has but, as he has, it points out exactly what I said. There is no specification, anywhere, ever, that shows the `<link>` element with a closing slash (nor any of the others such as `<img>`, `<input>`, etc.

Comment: @Rob — [Here's a spec that makes it mandatory](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.6), and [heres another one that makes a reference to one which also makes it mandatory](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html#writing-xhtml-documents). Neither of them are likely to apply in this case, but they do exist.

Comment: I've used relative links for a while now, specifically for hreflang, and everything works perfectly

Comment: @Quentin You are referring to XHTML. This is not XHTML as I stated and have stated everywhere, over and over, ad nauseum. People should get over this and quit doing unspecified things for no reason they can explain and for no purpose they can think of.

Comment: @Rob — Until unor edited in the `html` tag, there was no mention of any language in the question. That it wasn't XHTML was your assumption.

Comment: @Quentin How much would you wager he is using XHTML? Should we talk to unor about his assumption?

Answer (score 8):

Looks like it. This example [comes from the HTML5 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-alternate):

> For example, the following link is a French translation that uses the
>   PDF format:
>
> `<link rel=alternate type=application/pdf hreflang=fr href=manual-fr>`

Comment: The quote is correct, but its HTML syntax is wrong and potentially dangerous. Always quote your attributes.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I would _always_ recommend quoting HTML attributes as well, however, the above _quoted HTML5 syntax_ is not "wrong" in this instance. The attribute values only _need_ to be quoted if they contain spaces or a bunch of other special characters. (However, the slash is likely to trip up an HTML4 parser.)

Comment: @w3dk Aye, it's just a matter of being careful. Without quotes it becomes much easier to write incorrect HTML by dropping a `>` where it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

If possible do *always use absolute links* instead of relative ones.

**Why?**

Because relative links may cause crawl errors. Especially when it comes to alternate links you should make sure the bot finds exactly the URL you want it to crawl.

Further it is not a good idea to use parameters for language indication.

Please visit the following guides on multi language websites: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

And implementing hreflang: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: "Because relative links may cause crawl errors." - If a bot is unable to parse a relative URL (specifically where the spec states that relative URLs are permitted) then it's probably not a bot worth considering.

Comment: Not that I disagree with you on that "it is not a good idea to use parameters for language indication", but I find it greatly amusing that the link that you provide on the topic does, itself, use a parameter for language indication.

Comment: Both of you have a point, especially Google’s decision to use parameters.

Comment: But I'm speaking from experience. Relative linking often causes weird URLs being crawled and indexed. So besides the official standard allowing relative links I won't recommend it.

Comment: @Jase *"Do as I say, not as I do"*

Comment: @w3dk compare it to capital letters in URLs: you can use them but you may run into trouble. And I think the best strategy is to avoid troubles as far as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The definition of the [`href` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-link-href) for the [`link` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) says:

> […] must contain a [valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#valid-non-empty-url-potentially-surrounded-by-spaces)

This links to the definition of [valid non-empty URL](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#valid-non-empty-url), which links to the definition of [valid URL](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#valid-url), which says that is has to be a URL that

> conforms to the authoring conformance requirements in the URL standard

That URL standard is http://www.w3.org/TR/url/ (which is actually only a Working Draft from 2014), and this, of course, defines/allows [relative URLs](https://www.w3.org/TR/url/#concept-relative-url).

Or in other words (**tl;dr**): The `href` attribute is the same for `a`, `area`, and `link`.